# Using SimpleJSON C# help getting info

Tags: c#, json, simplejson

- *Do not say there is built in Unity Json or to download the Lindq for C# I am using SimpleJSON*

I am trying to read the json file and add the elements to a list so I can call them easier. I cannot figure out how to add all of "Heads" values to list.

So I could possibly call

```
listname[index].key
listname[key].value
```

to return somthing where I can get example.("Small_Cube_Head":{"Colors":{"Default"})

I basically want to be able to call the "Small_Cube_Head" and all color values

**JSON FILE**

```
{
"Heads":{
        "Large_Cube_Head":["Default","e97451"],
        "Medium_Cube_Head":["Default","ffffff","76d7ea","e97451","5fa777","f4c430","d0ff14","0047ab","e32636","fc419a","720b98","ff8b00","000000","848482"],
        "Small_Cube_Head":["Default"]
        }
    }

}
```

**code**

```
    /**
     * json: Returns the whole file as a String
     **/
    private void LoadJson()
    {
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Assets/JSON/PlayerPartsList.json"))
    {
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
        //Debug.Log(json);
        JSONNode node = JSON.Parse(json);

        Debug.Log(node["Heads"].Count); //returns 3 
        for (int i = 0; i < node["Heads"].Count; i++) {
            //headParts.Add(node["Heads"].);
            //Debug.Log(node["Heads"][i].Value.ToString());
            //Debug.Log(node["Heads"]["Small_Cube_Head"].Value);

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to put the key and values inside of "Heads" to a list, so with the JSON file there would be 3 (key,value) in a list. @Amy

Comment: Your JSON file does not contain valid JSON

Comment: `{"Default","e97451"}`, `{"Default","ffffff","76d7ea","e97451","5fa777","f4c430","d0ff14","0047ab","e32636","fc419a","720b98","ff8b00","000000","848482"}`, and `{"Default"}` are not valid JSON values

Comment: @Ruzihm Ah, you're right.  I was mentally changing it to an array.  Nice catch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as an off-topic question (typo) because the commented out code probably would work as intended if the json file were valid.

Comment: I fixed the file the commented out code still doesnt work @Ruzihm

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?  Are you getting an exception?  What actually happens?

Comment: "It doesn't work" sounds like your code doesn't compile. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: It just shows that everything is a Object @Ruzihm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Keys` like an enumerator to get each head name, and then you can loop through the count of that headName as the index

```
KeyEnumerator headNameEnum = node["Heads"].Keys;

while (headNameEnum.MoveNext())
{
    String headName = headNameEnum.Current().Value;

    Debug.Log("headName: " + headName); 
    for (int i=0; i < node["Heads"][headName].Count; i++) {
        String valueName = node["Heads"][headName][i].Value;
        Debug.Log("valueName: " + valueName);
    }

}
```